# Firmware issues at startup (Debian 9 - Firmware i915 and rtl8168g-2

Tags: linux, firmware, i915

Here is the problem displayed by dmesg

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep error
[...]
[    7.792141] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin failed with error -2
[...]
[   11.977510] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw failed with error -2
```

Same thing displayed in syslog:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep error
Nov 24 02:47:36 minibip kernel: [    6.546435] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin failed with error -2
Nov 24 02:47:37 minibip kernel: [    9.699957] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw failed with error -2
...
Nov 24 03:06:04 minibip kernel: [    6.100422] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin failed with error -2
...
Nov 24 03:06:04 minibip kernel: [    9.063138] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw failed with error -2
...
Nov 24 03:36:09 minibip kernel: [    6.110636] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin failed with error -2
...
Nov 24 03:36:09 minibip kernel: [    9.327847] r8169 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtl_nic/rtl8168g-2.fw failed with error -2
```

Some info about my server:

- Kernel: Linux minibip 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2
  (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Release: Debian GNU/Linux 9.6 (stretch)
- CPU: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU J3455 @ 1.50GHz
- RAM: 8GB

Questions:
How to solve this firmware issue?
Even with these errors the server seems to work fine, so I am wondering whether it is possible to tell the kernel not to try to load these firmwares

Comment: I found a solution by adding "contrib non-free" to my sources.list
Then, I installed: firmware-linux-nonfree and firmware-realtek
Problem solved!

Answer (score 7):

I would install the package: firmware-misc-nonfree

You will need to add the non-free repository then.

```
su
 -put in your root password

nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security stable/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main

apt-get update
apt-get upgrade

apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree
```

Or, you could use synaptic.